# SQL Server 2005 merging rows where multiple exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this:

```
    select * from tbRegInfo
    clubID  personID    Sex Birth Year  Birth Month JoinedDate  leftDate
    C77     745         M   1942        5           14/05/2002  09/09/2010
    C77     246         M   2008        5           15/04/2009  14/01/2011
    C77     246         M   2008        5           16/09/2008  27/10/2008
    C77     59          M   1941        5           07/09/2011  24/01/2012
    C77     498         F   1945        1           12/03/2011  NULL
    C77     478         M   1935        6           07/06/2010  NULL
    B92     367         F   1955        8           18/10/1988  NULL
    B92     84          M   2006        6           03/07/2008  NULL
    B92     836         M   1965        7           07/11/2008  18/01/2013
    B92     833         F   1962        4           13/01/1995  13/03/2000
    B92     833         F   1962        4           05/09/2002  NULL
```

some people have more than 1 row in the table because they have joined, left and joined again.  I want to produce a query like this

```
    clubID  personID    Sex BirthYear   BirthMonth  JoinedDate  leftDate    joinedDate2 leftDate2
    C77     745         M   1942        5           14/05/2002  09/09/2010      
    C77     246         M   2008        5           15/04/2009  14/01/2011  16/09/2008  27/10/2008
    C77     59          M   1941        5           07/09/2011  24/01/2012      
    C77     498         F   1945        1           12/03/2011          
    C77     478         M   1935        6           07/06/2010          
    B92     367         F   1955        8           18/10/1988          
    B92     84          M   2006        6           03/07/2008          
    B92     836         M   1965        7           07/11/2008  18/01/2013      
    B92     833         F   1962        4           13/01/1995  13/03/2000  05/09/2002
```

where, if there is a second joining date, the value appears in another column on the same row.  I realise I need to do join when selecting but I can't figure out how to do this at all

Comment: You really want to produce such a table? I would understand if you need such a query(search for `PIVOT`).

Comment: [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is indeed the way to go, as @TimSchmelter already suggested. Otherwise, the main problem is that you'd need to join the table to itself, and the number of joins would be determined by the maximum number of times a person left and re-joined. That means you'd have no flexibility unless you'd go for sp_executesql and build the sql dynamically, which is lots of work, overkill for this scenario and generally not very nice IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very long article : )  
1- select distint column without JoinedDate and leftDate 
2- create unique column with other columns (`Id` column)

```
 select 
 distinct [clubID],[personID],[Sex],[Birth Year],[Birth Month],
 ([clubID] +'-'+ convert(nvarchar,[personID]) +'-'+ convert(nvarchar,[Sex])+'-'+ 
 convert(nvarchar,[Birth Year]) + '-' +convert(nvarchar,[Birth Month])) as Id   
 into #dt 
 from tbRegInfo
```

3- create other temp table for select JoinedDate

```
SELECT   b.JoinedDate, a.Id, COUNT(*) AS Count
into #dt2       
FROM            dbo.#dt AS a INNER JOIN
dbo.tbRegInfo AS b ON 
(b.[clubID] +'-'+ convert(nvarchar,b.[personID]) +'-'+ 
convert(nvarchar,b.[Sex])+'-'+ convert(nvarchar,b.[Birth Year]) 
+ '-' +convert(nvarchar,b.[Birth Month]))=a.Id

GROUP BY b.JoinedDate, a.Id
ORDER BY Count
```

4- add columns for JoinedDate. it will add columns for max repeated JoinedDate. I mean if a person 5 time joined and left. it will add

JoinedDate,JoinedDate1,JoinedDate2,JoinedDate... JoinedDate5

```
 declare @Id nvarchar(250) = ''
 declare @date date
 declare @count int
 declare @counter int =2
 declare @mySql nvarchar(4000)=''

  ALTER TABLE #dt ADD JoinedDate date

  select @count =max(Count) from #dt2

  while @counter<=@count
  begin

    set @mySql =  'ALTER TABLE #dt ADD JoinedDate' 
       + convert(nvarchar,@counter-1) + ' date '
    exec (@mySql )

    set @counter= @counter+1
  end
```

5- with cursor add Joineddate to related columns

```
DECLARE my_cursor  CURSOR FOR select Id, JoinedDate, Count from #dt2 
    open my_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO  @Id,@date,@count
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
        BEGIN

        set @counter=1
                set @mySql=''
                while @counter<=@count
                begin
                    if  @counter=1
                    begin
        set @mySql =  ' update #dt set JoinedDate =  ' + char(39) + 
            convert(nvarchar,@date) + char(39) + ' where Id= ' 
            +  char(39) +  @Id +  char(39)
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        set @mySql =  ' update #dt set 
                     JoinedDate' + convert(nvarchar,@counter-1)  + '  =  ' 
                     + char(39) +  convert(nvarchar,@date) + char(39) + ' 
                       where Id= ' +  char(39) +  @Id +  char(39)
                    end
                     exec (@mySql )

                    set @counter= @counter+1
                end

    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO   @Id,@date,@count
END

close my_cursor
deallocate my_cursor
```

------------  JOINEDDATE is finished now LEFTDATE begining ----

1- insert leftdate temp table with join #dt

```
SELECT        b.leftDate, a.Id, COUNT(*) AS Count
into #dt3       
FROM            dbo.#dt AS a INNER JOIN
dbo.tbRegInfo AS b ON 
(b.[clubID] +'-'+ convert(nvarchar,b.[personID]) +'-'
 + convert(nvarchar,b.[Sex])+'-'+ convert(nvarchar,b.[Birth Year]) 
  + '-' +convert(nvarchar,b.[Birth Month]))=a.Id

GROUP BY b.leftDate, a.Id
ORDER BY Count
```

2- add columns for Leftdate

```
  ALTER TABLE #dt ADD LeftDate date

    select @count =max(Count) from #dt3

  set @mySql =''
   set @counter=2
  while @counter<=@count
  begin

    set @mySql =  'ALTER TABLE #dt ADD LeftDate' 
     + convert(nvarchar,@counter-1) + ' date '
    exec (@mySql )

    set @counter= @counter+1
  end
```

3- insert Leftdate to #dt  with cursor

```
DECLARE my_cursor_sec  CURSOR FOR select distinct Id, LeftDate,Count from #dt3  
    open my_cursor_sec
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor_sec INTO  @Id,@date,@count
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
        BEGIN

                set @counter=1
                set @mySql=''
                while @counter<=@count
                begin
                    if  @counter=1
                    begin
         set @mySql =  ' update #dt set LeftDate =  ' 
                  + char(39) +  convert(nvarchar,@date) + char(39) 
                  + ' where Id= ' +  char(39) +  @Id +  char(39)
                    end
                    else
                    begin
         set @mySql =  ' update #dt set LeftDate' 
                + convert(nvarchar,@counter-1)  + '  =  ' + char(39) 
                 +  convert(nvarchar,@date) + char(39) + ' where Id= ' 
                   +  char(39) +  @Id +  char(39)
                    end
                         exec (@mySql )

                    set @counter= @counter+1
                end

    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor_sec INTO   @Id,@date,@count
END

close my_cursor_sec
deallocate my_cursor_sec
```

4- now we dont need Id column

```
ALTER TABLE #dt  DROP COLUMN Id
```

5- finally select  rows

```
select distinct * from #dt
```

-- results

```
clubID   personID    Sex  Birth Year  Birth Month JoinedDate LeftDate
-------- ----------- ---- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
B92      84          M    2006        6           2008-07-03 NULL
B92      367         F    1955        8           1988-10-18 NULL
B92      833         F    1962        4           2002-09-05 2000-03-13
B92      836         M    1965        7           2008-11-07 2013-01-18
C77      59          M    1941        5           2011-09-07 2012-01-24
C77      246         M    2008        5           2009-04-15 2011-01-14
C77      478         M    1935        6           2010-06-07 NULL
C77      498         F    1945        1           2011-03-12 NULL
C77      745         M    1942        5           2002-05-14 2010-09-09
```